# Looping and updating data in React

Tags: json, reactjs, rest

So quite new to React here (mostly backend and devops engineer). I need to fix a bug as the person usually responsible is not available currently.

One of the REST endpoint is formatting dates incorrectly while sending the data to the backend. The data expected from the endpoint for a PUT is

```
 "items": [
    {
        "uuid": "abc7aba1-47ad-46d1-a3a5-d26ff55e4cf8",
        "item_id": "21626227",
        "item_description": "Test",
        "item_schedule": {
            "uuid": "37f8ca4c-6469-4bfb-822e-acfbc02e502e",
            "start_date": "2018-12-04",
            "end_date": "2018-12-06",
            "interval": 3,
            "unit": "days",
            "occurrence": 1
            "schedule_dates": [
                {
                    "uuid": "d5b73ac5-be77-40c5-b11b-45034f70f81f",
                    "planned_date": "2018-12-04",
                    "custom": true
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "uuid": "7abca4f4-1717-4136-aec6-3a37b4971c81",
        "item_id": "21626229",
        "item_description": "Test 2",
        "maintenance_plan": "31001827",
        "item_schedule": {
            "uuid": "5de45d6e-81e8-4c86-9eb2-31c71089c876",
            "start_date": null,
            "end_date": null,
            "interval": null,
            "unit": "",
            "occurrence": null,
            "schedule_dates": [
                {
                    "uuid": "da7ed2e4-053e-4f1d-80ca-2d6d258e8a08",
                    "planned_date": "2018-12-13",
                    "custom": true
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

]
Instead what we get for all the dates, i.e. start_date, end_date and planned_dates is (skipping all the right stuff here..)

```
 "end_date": "2018-12-05T13:00:00.000Z",
 "start_date": "2018-12-03T13:00:00.000Z"
 "planned_date" : "2018-12-03T13:00:00.000Z"
```

When creating a new schedule for a new item, the old schedule data is incorrectly formatted.

I have tried to loop over all the items and the relevant schedule and dates and correctly format them , but doesn't seem to work.

Do I need to use map here instead of foreach?

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => ({
 save: (value, notes) => dispatch(ItemDetailAction.saveLocal(
  props.value.merge(
  Map(Object.assign(
    {
      notes: notes.setIn([0, 'created'], undefined),
      uuid: props.value.get('uuid'),
    },

    props.value.getIn(['item', 'type']) === 'P' && {
      items: props.value
        .get('items').forEach((item) => {
          console.log(item.get('item_schedule'));
          const start_date = item.get('item_schedule').get('start_date');
          if (start_date !== '') {
            const formatted_date = moment(start_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
           //not updating the date-format below in the same array.
           item.get('item_schedule').set('start_date',formatted_date);
           item.setIn(['item_schedule', 'start_date'],formatted_date);
           // this still prints the wrong date-format
            console.log(item.get('item_schedule').get('start_date'));
          }
        }),
    },
  )),
),
true,
{
  then: () => {
    props.onCancel();
    dispatch(actions.getItemListTable(FilterMaintenance.asParams(props.filters)));
  },
}, )), });
```

Comment: Please add what you are getting in `props.value
        .get('items')`

Comment: I am getting all the correct data and the date is getting formatted correctly as well, if I do console.log(formatted_date) , however the part of item.get('item_schedule').set('start_date',formatted_date) is not working. I mean the same items that I am looping are not getting updated. There is no error.